# convert object with joda time arrayList to json

Tags: java, json, arraylist, jackson, jodatime

I have an object with the following fields (`DateTime` is from joda time):

```
(DateTime dt, String a, String b)
```

For my purposes I have an arraylist of these objects and I need to turn them into json String to store in shared preferences in android.

I have started using Jackson I can't figure out how to convert the object (with nested object) arraylist into the string I need.

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I have tried with Gson but it doesn't work with joda time, currently I am away from my PC so I don't have code

Answer (score 0):

Put [jackson-datatype-joda](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda) in your project and register it on your `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
```

Then you can serialize and deserialize Joda classes to your heart's content.

```
ArrayList<DateTime> times = new ArrayList<DateTime>();
times.add(DateTime.now());
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(times);
System.out.println(json);
```

Outputs:

```
["2015-11-02T15:45:02.070-05:00"]
```

Comment: I don't think you read it properly, arraylist of objects which hold (Datetime, string, string) not just the date time

Comment: I read it correctly, I just assumed you were capable of writing a class to hold a `DateTime` and two Strings by yourself. Is that not the case?

Comment: I am sorry if you were offended by this, I do have a class called "Task" which holds a DateTime and 2 string, I would like to keep one arrayList to hold these objects. in your example you showed an arrayList of only DateTime objects and not nested. will this method work for my object too?

Comment: Yep! Just switch `ArrayList<DateTime>` with `ArrayList<Task>`. As long as `Task` has getters for the three fields then you'll be good to go. And don't worry, I wasn't offended. It's tough gauging people by these small interactions on the web. ;)

Comment: if I can bother you guys a little more,
objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, MyObj.class)); 
returns a databind,JsonMappingException. any idea? (MyObj is (DateTime, String, String))

Comment: I've had better luck using `TypeReference` like this: `objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<ArrayList<MyObj>>() {})`. If that doesn't work, it's probably better to create a new question on SO. :-\

Comment: @Gmodjackass - If this answer worked for you, can you please accept it? If not, please provide your own answer if you found a different solution or comment for further clarification. Thanks!